# dmake: Error code 137, while making 'Shell escape' after using -Wl,-Ttext-segment=0x855555000000 and /proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space value is 2

Tags: linux, multithreading, runtime-error, exit-code, thread-sanitizer

I am getting following error message while running my thread-sanitized  executable. (I have used `-fPIC` and `-fsanitized=thread` flag at compilation , `-fsanitize=thread -Wl`and '-pie' flag during executable time):

```
FATAL: ThreadSanitizer can not mmap the shadow memory (something is mapped at 0x2aab6c8a7000 < 0x7cf000000000)
FATAL: Make sure to compile with -fPIE and to link with -pie.
dmake:  Error code 1, while making 'Shell escape'
```

However after going through [this BugZilla link](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=59410), I have checked `/proc/sys/kernel/randomize_va_space` and enabled randomization with value 2. I have also specified where to load PIE via a linker switch `-Ttext-segment 0x855555000000`.

Now I have no more FATAL error but I have encountered with new error message :

```
dmake:  Error code 137, while making 'Shell escape'
```

I don't know where I am making mistake with flags. Any idea?

Comment: I got the answer ,probably I am trying to use Kernel Virtual Address Space,and bcoz of that  OS is generating KILL -9 signal to process (which is Error Code 137). But now my question is that , then how should I know which address I will give for text segment flag ?